# str_replace using the_permalink()

Tags: wordpress, str-replace

Trying to use str_replace to remove a directory from the_permalink() in Wordpress:

```
$the_old_link = the_permalink();
$the_new_link = str_replace('/unwanted_folder', '', $the_old_link);
```

Comment: What is the issue you are facing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `the_permalink()`, you have to use `get_permalink()` if you want to store a value in PHP. `the_permalink()` is meant for displaying output, not for setting variables.

See the following:
http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_permalink
http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_permalink

Answer (score 0):

yes, you need to use `get_permalink()`. This is used to save the permalink in a variable

your codes would see something like this

`$the_old_link = get_permalink();`

`$the_new_link = str_replace( '/unwanted_folder', '', $the_old_link );`

then where you want to use the new link just **echo** it.

an instance can be `<a href="<?php echo $the_new_link; ?>" class"new-link">link</a>`